# $\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^3$ matrix/canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, change-of-basis

let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear map and given by
$f\pmatrix{1\\2}=\pmatrix{2\\1\\1}, f\pmatrix{2\\2}=\pmatrix{0\\4\\2}$

(1) Define the matrix of $f$ in regards to the canonical basis, meaning that the canonical basis is chosen in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

(2) Calculate the rank of this matrix.

My ideas for 1). I have calculated the image of the map for the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$f\pmatrix{0\\1}= f\left(-\frac{1}{2} \pmatrix{2\\2}+\pmatrix{1\\2}\right)=\pmatrix{2\\-1\\0}$

$f\pmatrix{1\\0}= f\left(\pmatrix{2\\2}-\pmatrix{1\\2}\right)=\pmatrix{-2\\3\\1}$

so the first matrix is given by $M_1 = \pmatrix{-2 & 2\\3 & 1\\1 & 0}$.
But I am stuck here, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for the first part is correct (except for a missing $-$ for the first vector).

For the second part, the answer will probably depend a bit on your definition of the rank of a matrix. A standard way for determining the rank is to use Gaussian elimination in order to determine the [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) of the given matrix. Alternatively, you could think about what the maximal rank of a $3 \times 2$ matrix can be and then maybe find a reason why this actually is the rank here.

Comment: Thank you! have corrected the minus error, but the rank is row rank is 2, correct? It has not maximal rank?

Comment: Yes, the rank is 2 (which is the maximal possible rank here since the rank of a $n\times m$ matrix can never be more than $\min\{n,m\}$.